# How to Loop a MotionLayout Animation?

Tags: java, android, android-motionlayout

I'm trying out the `MotionLayout` and from what I've learned it seems to be used for transitioning from point `A` to `B`. **Is there a looping property that goes from `A` to `B` and restarts?**

I haven't tried anything out yet. Just doing my research before actually coding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer [@hoford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2558442/hoford) provided does something similar, but I wanted something simple.

This is my approach:

```
MotionLayout motionLayout = findViewById(R.id.motionLayout);

        motionLayout.transitionToEnd();

        motionLayout.setTransitionListener(new MotionLayout.TransitionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onTransitionStarted(MotionLayout motionLayout, int i, int i1)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionChange(MotionLayout motionLayout, int i, int i1, float v)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionCompleted(MotionLayout motionLayout, int i)
            {
                if(!looped)
                    motionLayout.transitionToStart();

                else
                    motionLayout.transitionToEnd();

                looped = !looped;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionTrigger(MotionLayout motionLayout, int i, boolean b, float v)
            {

            }
        });
```

Where `looped` starts off as `false`. It does this quick jitter on the 1st trigger of `onTransitionCompleted` cause it tries to go from start to end and from end to start sort of at the same time(don't ask me why. It just does). But, it works fine because it's hardly noticeable for what I want it for.

Comment: Yes this is a good code solution.
As a small improvement I recommend using TransitionAdapter as you only have to implement the one method.

Comment: I'll definitely take a look into that. Thanks. I upvoted your answer cause it does give me some insight into some other areas that I could explore.

Answer (score 2):

No
You can achieve it with 3 states (A, B & C) using in Transitions A->B, B->C & C->A.
Setting all of them to autoTransition="animateToEnd".

It might work with two Transitions A->B and B->A setting B->A autoTransition="jumpToEnd".

It is typically not good to have an animation looping forever on screen.
If you just need something to repeat X times consider KeyCycles or KeyTimeCycles.

(Short Videos on the subjects: [KeyCycle](https://youtu.be/qWmU6emSQ5k)
[KeyTimeCycle](https://youtu.be/us0sOEq_fck) )

Comment: Yeah, I thought about something like that. Wanted to double check if there was something more appropriate lol